# docker removed, but is still updating

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I used docker for a while, but i don't need it anmyore. So i removed it from my Ubuntu 16.04. When i try "sudo apt-get remove docker" it says that there is nothing, but when i run "sudo apt-get update" i get many lines like this:

> Ign:45 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu §(lsb_release/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata

So it's still updating docker.

Does anyone know how to remove docker completely from Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sanath already stated you still have entries in /etc/apt/source.list for the docker package repository. You need to remove these (look for lines containing docker in that file and remove them).

To explain what these entries are:
/etc/apt/sorce.list lists all sources for packages which you can install/upgrade using apt. When you followed the steps in the installation of docker you added a line with the address of the docker package repository there. Now `apt update` always polls that repo to check if it contains any upgrades of a package you have installed.

Now because that address contains docker you falsely asume that you still have docker installed, which is not the case. Docker is simply part of the url of one of the repositories that is queried for updates.

Answer (score 2):

It's because some of the entries are still present in.

nano /etc/apt/source.list

Remove lines which is having docker repository.

Then do apt-get update